# Inheriting from a class and adding an additional property

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have a class in one application - **that I cannot change** (legacy) - that is inside of a assembly (DLL file):

```
public class ShippingMethod
{
    public string ShipMethodCode { get; set; }
    public string ShipMethodName { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingCost { get; set; }

    public List<ShippingMethod> GetAllShippingMethods()
    {
    ......
    }
}
```

I have a second application that is referencing that assembly (DLL file) and needs to populate a drop-down with all the Shipping Methods. Ex: "UPS - $3.25"

The issue is that it needs to be using the correct format for different currencies. Ex: $3.25 or 3.25€ depending on a parameter called CountryID.

I have written a function `String DisplayMoney(Decimal Amount, Integer CountryID)` that will return the correct format of the amount.

Now I need to apply this function to every shipping method and save it into a new list.
What is the best way to do this?

I can create another class called LocalizedShippingMethods as follows:

```
public class LocalizedShippingMethod
{
    public ShippingMethod ShipMethod { get; set; }
    public string LocalizedShippingCost { get; set; }
}
```

Is this the best way to accomplish this? Is there a better way to do this using inheritance? And if I use inheritance, how do I get the values from the first LIST into the NEW LIST?

Comment: Rename LocalizedShippingCost to LocalShippingCurrency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed a good method of doing it. You can use a pretty quick Linq query to pull the old `List` into the new one:

```
List<LocalizedShippingMethod> Translate(List<ShippingMethod> oldList)
{
  return oldList.Select(a => new LocalizedShippingMethod
     {
         // Initialize properties according to however you translate them
     }).ToList();
}
```

Additionally, to make this more streamlined and obvious, you could do any of the following to aid in the translation:

- Create a constructor for `LocalizedShippingMethod` that takes in a `ShippingMethod` and properly sets the properties
- Create a static method on `LocalizedShippingMethod` that takes in a `ShippingMethod` and returns an initialized `LocalizedShippingMethod`
- Create an operator on `LocalizedShippingMethod` that converts from a `ShippingMethod`
- Create an extension method on `ShippingMethod`, call it `ToLocalized()` that returns a `LocalizedShippingMethod`

Comment: Would this copy the data of the list property by property?

Comment: It will copy the contents of the `List` object by object; you'll have to initialize the properties within the `LocalizedShippingMethod` initialization block to actually create that object properly.

Comment: Thanks. This is way I did it:
`LocalizedShippingMethodList = (from S in OriginalShippingMethods` `select new LocalizedShippingMethod { `
`ShippingMethod = S, `
`LocalizedShippingCost = DisplayMoney(S.ShippingCost, CountryID) `
`}).ToList();`

In this way, each object is not copied, but rather referenced by another variable. (`ShippingMethod = S, `)

Comment: Oh, that's definitely right - I missed that that was the same class when I was looking over it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create an extension method for the ShippingMethod class?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is whatever way works best *for you.*  If you're the person who's going to have to maintain this code, what will make your life the easiest down the road?

Once you've answered that question, *that* is the best solution.